# Shell script on "read" accept via both enter key and tab key

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting, read

in shell script when you have the following :

```
read my_variable
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd> is the key that saves your input.

is there a way to make <kbd>Tab</kbd> accomplish the same as <kbd>Enter</kbd> without removing <kbd>Enter</kbd>'s functionality?

Comment: Using `read -d $'\t' variable` would use a tab _instead_ of a newline as the delimiter, but that's not what you want, right?

Comment: no I'd like both ideally. but thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be overkill but you could obtain that by using `read -e`, which enables the Readline facility on the `read` utility. At that point your desired result would be only one key-binding away.

Careful though that Readline brings along many other functionalities too, like completion, history, etc., which you might not want for a simple `read my_variable`. If those are undesirable, you have to explicitly clear the key-bindings and disable the functionalities you don't want for your `read -e`.

Sample proof-of-concept from command-line:

```bash
(bind 'TAB: accept-line'; IFS= read -re var && echo "$var" || echo ko)
```

You can do that in a script too, although `bind` will give a warning (which you can still mute by redirecting `2>/dev/null`).

An alternative to `bind` commands in a script is to provide a custom inputrc file prior to invoking the script that you want to be affected. It's not necessary to have a real file, a Here Document suffices.

The above example made through scripts:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

export INPUTRC=/dev/fd/3

script2.sh 3<<EOF
TAB: accept-line
set history-size 0
EOF
# this example 'inputrc'-like file also disables history support
```

The above script prepares the custom inputrc file as a Here Document on file-descriptor 3, which the shell running `script2.sh` will read as indicated by the `INPUTRC` environment variable.

Then `script2.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo start
bind -q accept-line 2>/dev/null  # shows which keys are configured to accept input
IFS= read -re var && echo "$var" || echo ko
echo end
```

Before waiting for input on the `read`, the script will print something like:

```
accept-line can be invoked via "\C-i", "\C-j", "\C-m".
```

showing that <kbd>Tab</kbd> (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl-I</kbd> shown above as `\C-i`) accepts a line just as well as a <kbd>Return</kbd> (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl-M</kbd>, carriage-return) or a newline (<kbd>Ctrl-J</kbd>).

For a more "real world" example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

bind 'TAB: accept-line' &>/dev/null

echo "enter your name:"
IFS= read -re var 

echo "your name is: $var"
```

If you go down this path, have a look at [Readline user's guide](https://tiswww.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html), at least the reduced one in your `man bash`. The `set convert-meta off` setting among others may worth a particular mention in order to have better support for non-ascii characters.

Comment: here's what I used : `#!/bin/bash; bind 'TAB: accept-line' &>/dev/null; echo "enter your name:"; IFS= read -e var; echo "your name is: $var"` thank you very much. It blows my mind that this is actually possible, yes there are caveats but I think I can work around them. what does `IFS` do?

Comment: @tatsu try without the `IFS=` and see what happens when you type leading or trailing spaces ;-) Actually, I had also forgot a worthy `-r` to the `read`, which prevents it interpret backslashed characters. (Normally one wants them untouched in cases like yours)

Answer (score 1):

The way that could be done in general is by setting the `termios(3)`/`stty(1)` `VEOL`/`eol` special char ("alternate end-of-line") to Tab. On systems which support it, `VEOL2`/`eol2` could be used, too.

Unfortunately, the `read` shell built-in will always try to read up to a newline (or another delimiter in `bash` if `-d` was used, with no support for multiple delimiters).

One way that could be worked around is by using a `var=$(dd count=1 bs=big)` command substitution instead of `read`. Here is an example of such a kludge:

```
while :; do

        t=$(stty -g)
        stty eol ^I
        trap : INT
        var=$(dd bs=10k count=1 2>/dev/null; echo x)
        stty "$t"
        trap - INT
        var=${var%x}
        [ "$var" ] || break
        var=${var%[$'\n\t']}

        printf '{%s}\n' "$var"

done
```

The `t=(stty -g)` and `stty "$t"` will save and restore the terminal settings.

The `trap : INT` and `trap - INT` will prevent a Control-C from killing the shell/loop (with all the complications and shell-specific behavior that that entails) and let it only kill the `dd` and the command substitution.

The `$(...; echo x)` followed by `${var%x}` is a trick to prevent a trailing newline from being stripped from the command substituition; this is necessary in order to be able to differentiate between the user having pressed just `Enter` for an empty variable, and `Control-C` or `Control-D` to exit the loop.

Finally, the `${var%[$'\n\t']}` will remove the trailing newline or tab from the variable. In shells which do not support `$'...'` strings like `dash` or `yash`, that could be replaced with:

```
nltab='<literal tab here>
'
...
var=${var%[$nltab]}
```